# How to get a list of libraries ffmpeg has linked to (static ffmpeg libraries)?

Tags: c, compilation, linker, ffmpeg, libraries

I have compiled Ffmpeg (1.0) with newt configuration:

```
./configure  --disable-doc  --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe  --disable-ffserver    --disable-avdevice   --disable-avfilter   --disable-pthreads  --disable-everything --enable-muxer=flv --enable-encoder=flv --enable-encoder=h263 --disable-mmx  --disable-shared   --prefix=bin/  --disable-protocols --disable-network --disable-debug  --disable-asm --disable-stripping
```

It compiled - no errors - headers and libs (static `.a`) are in place. (special experimental cigwin, experimental gcc, with no asm options, and no known by ffmpeg platform defines) (yet I have compiled and tested boost on it)

Now I try to compile my app. I get next exceptions:

```
../ffmpeg-1.0/bin/lib/libavcodec.a: error: undefined reference to 'exp'
../ffmpeg-1.0/bin/lib/libavcodec.a: error: undefined reference to 'log'
```

My compiler build line looks like this:

```
g++ -static -emit-swf -o CloudClient.swf  -I../boost/boost_libraries/install-dir/include -I../ffmpeg-1.0/bin/include -L../boost/boost_libraries/install-dir/lib -L../ffmpeg-1.0/bin/lib \
    timer.o \
    audio_encoder.o \
    audio_generator.o \
    video_encoder.o \
    video_generator_rainbow.o \
    simple_synchronizer.o \
    multiplexer.o \
    transmitter.o \
    graph_runner.o \
    cloud_client.o \
    -pthread \
    -lswscale \
    -lavutil \
    -lavformat \
    -lavcodec \
    -lboost_system \
    -lboost_date_time \
    -lboost_thread
```

So as you see quite complex and I already have all object files compiled and ready... Only one thing left - link it all to ffmpeg (striped from ffmpeg version compiled with boost)

Tried adding `-lm` -  no help...

Well here my question is - how to get list of libraries ffmpeg linked to (like `-lm` etc)?

Comment: find the location of math library and add it to library path "-L" and try.

Comment: I think you just put them in the wrong order. You need to add `-lm` to the *end* of the command line, not the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

If in Linux, try

```
ldd /path/to/ffmpeg-binary
```

or

```
ldd `which ffmpeg`
```

Comment: he's unable to compile his app; ldd (guess loader dependencies) list only shared libraries provided the app is already compiled successfully.

Comment: Did you compile the libraries with '-static' as well? or, for 'configure' script --enable-static option.